# Managed memory use of MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream()

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Will `MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream(0, len)` allocate a managed block of memory of size `len`, or will it allocate smaller buffer that acts as a sliding window over the unmanaged data?

I wonder because I aim to replace an intermediate buffer for deserialization that is a MemoryStream today, which is giving me trouble for large datasets, both because of the size of the buffer and because of LOH fragmentation.

If the viewstream's internal buffer becomes the same size then making this switch wouldn't make sense.

**Edit:**

In a quick test I found these numbers when comparing the MemoryStream to the MemoryMapped file. Readings from `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)/1024` and `Process.GetCurrentProcess.VirtualMemorySize64/1024`

Allocate an 1GB memory stream:

```
                     Managed           Virtual 
Initial:               81 kB        190 896 kB
After alloc:    1 024 084 kB      1 244 852 kB
```

As expected, a gig of both managed and virtual memory.
Now, for the MemoryMappedFile:

```
                     Managed           Virtual 
Initial:               81 kB        189 616 kB    
MMF allocated:         84 kB        189 684 kB
1GB viewstream allocd: 84 kB      1 213 368 kB
Viewstream disposed:   84 kB        190 964 kB
```

So using a not very scientific test, my assumption is that the ViewStream uses only unmanaged data. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MMF like that doesn't solve your problem.  A program bombs on OOM because there isn't hole in the virtual memory space big enough to fit the allocation.  You are still consuming VM address space with an MMF, as you can tell.

Using a small sliding view would be a workaround, but that isn't any different from writing to a file.  Which is what an MMF does when you remap the view, it needs to flush the dirty pages to disk.  Simply streaming to a FileStream is the proper workaround.  That still uses RAM, the file system cache helps make writing fast.  If you've got a gigabyte of RAM available, not hard to come by these days, then writing to a FileStream is just a memory-to-memory copy.  Very fast, 5 gigabytes/sec and up.  The file gets written in a lazy fashion in the background.

Trying too hard to keep data in memory is unproductive in Windows.  Private data in memory is backed by the paging file and will be written to that file when Windows needs the RAM for other processes.  And read back when you access it again.  That's slow, the more memory you use, the worse it gets.  Like any demand-paged virtual memory operating system, the distinction between disk and memory is a small one.

Comment: I must have misunderstood something completely, a 32bit .NET program that bombs with an out of memory exception in my experience has bombed because it has hit the ~1.3-1.5Gb ceiling on total managed memory use  *or* (just as commonly) has fragmented the LOH and tries to allocate a large array such as when using large memory streams.

Comment: It sounds good if Windows I/O makes a short-lived temp file essentially be an in-memory copy, I will give it a try. Anything I need to think about when using a FileStream for this, to avoid it being flushed to disk?

Comment: No, it is a VM limit, unmanaged allocations matter just as much.  It is not up to you to control how much RAM is used for the FileStream data.  You cannot affect it, other than indirectly by the amount of data you write and what other processes run on the machine that use the cache as well.

Comment: I was hoping to use the vast amount of VM that is available *outside* the process (for a 32bit application in a 64bit OS) but unfortunately I need to be able to seek in this data. And the allocation of the ViewStream/ViewAccessor will allocate the memory in the process which is eating from the 2GB limit. So I will remove the seeking/buffering requirement (i.e. have single pass serialization), or use a FileStream as my temporary buffer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

given the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx it seems to me that you get a sliding window, at least that is what i interpret when reading the example.

Here the example for convenience:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes 
        long length = 0x20000000; // 512 megabytes 

        // Create the memory-mapped file. 
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data", FileMode.Open,"ImgA"))
        {
            // Create a random access view, from the 256th megabyte (the offset) 
            // to the 768th megabyte (the offset plus length). 
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
            {
                int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor));
                MyColor color;

                // Make changes to the view. 
                for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
                {
                    accessor.Read(i, out color);
                    color.Brighten(10);
                    accessor.Write(i, ref color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct MyColor
{
    public short Red;
    public short Green;
    public short Blue;
    public short Alpha;

    // Make the view brigher. 
    public void Brighten(short value)
    {
        Red = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Red + value);
        Green = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Green + value);
        Blue = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Blue + value);
        Alpha = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Alpha + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see in that example whether the creation of `accessor` will be e.g. a 64k buffer to read the 512MB block, or whether it is actually a 512MB buffer that is allocated.

Comment: to me it seems like a 512mb buffer that is allocated